# LINQ Compare TimeSpan

Tags: c#, linq, timespan

in my database a have rows like

[image]

And in my Blazor app i need to find the match if the clock is 15 minutes before TimeStart AND 15 minuttes before TimeEnd.

If the clock is between 9.45 and 10.45 I want RowID 27

If the clock is between 10.45 and 11.45 I want RowID 28

I have tried:

```
 IEnumerable<Overview> mydata = from a in overview
    where (a.Timestart > Minus15Min && 
           a.Timeend.Value.Subtract(new TimeSpan(00, 15, 00)) > Minus15Min)
    select a;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very symmetrical about Start and End but your code treats them differently. Also, you have two `>` for a range, that is very doubtful.

How about

```
var nowPlus15 = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
IEnumerable<Overview> mydata = from a in overview
    where (a.Timestart <= nowPlus15  && 
           a.Timeend > nowPlus15)
    select a;
```